# refuse ajax submit if fields are empty jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, validation

Let's say I have a simple form. I use this jquery piece of code to get the result using ajax on my form page.

```
function sendquery()
{
$("#form").submit();
 var url = "form.php";

$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: url,
       data: $("#form").serialize(),
       success: function(data)
       {
           $("#output").html(data);
       }
     });

return false;  
}
```

Quite simple. What I want now is to validate the form by adding a class, let's say "blank" to inputs with empty value, and don't allow the form to be submitted. It shouldn't be too hard, but whatever i've tried will just break my form.

How can I do it?

Comment: Google 'jquery validate plugin'.

Comment: Doesn't really help, I still can't get it to refuse to submit form if !valid

Comment: Yes you can, check the form is valid before you send the submit request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need [jQuery validate plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) , and ......

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $('#formId').validate({
    submitHandler:function(form)
    {       
        $(form).ajaxSubmit({
        success:function(response)
        {
            //do stuff on success
        },
        dataType:'json'
    });

    },
    errorLabelContainer: "#error_message_box",
    wrapper: "li",
    rules:
    {
        name:"required",
        category:"required"

    },
    messages:
    {
        name:"name required",
        category:"category required"
    }
});

});
```